# tikz `trim axis {left,right}` and y-axis automatic at margin side in a twocolumn layout

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, two-column

I have a few graphs plotted using pgfplots:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
0; 1
2; 3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
        \begin{axis}[
            height=5.5cm,
            scale only axis,
            width=\linewidth,
        ]
    \addplot table[col sep=semicolon] {data.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I personally love the fact that my graph axis is flush with the text. Gives me a very pleasant feeling.

However, I am now converting my document to two-column layout. When a figure gets into the right column, the labels of the left axis flow into the left column. I can of course manually throw my axis to the other side of the graph, but I'm wondering whether it's possible to have the correct options (`ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right`) automatically inserted when my picture flows in the right column.

[image: Example of the labels overflowing into text]

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
0; 1
2; 3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
        \begin{axis}[
            height=5.5cm,
            scale only axis,
            width=\linewidth,
        ]
    \addplot table[col sep=semicolon] {data.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```